# Error 'Provide valid app ID in Instagram' even adding a valid 'app_id' and a valid 'access_token'

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

To make the call, the `access_token` is needed, but when making the call, an `app_id` error appears, even adding to the data, it still returns an error. How should I proceed?

```
import requests

access_token = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
app_id = 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB'
id_facebook_page = 'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC'
get_instagram_business_account = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/' + id_facebook_page + '?fields=instagram_business_account&access_token=' + access_token

instagram_business_account = 'DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD'

image = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/95/Test_image.jpg'
text = 'Hello World'

formData = {
    'image_url': image,
    'caption': text,
    'access_token': access_token,
    'app_id': app_id
  }

options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formData
  }

container = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/' + instagram_business_account + '/media'
response = requests.get(container, data=options)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: `requests.get` should probably be `requests.post` ...?

Comment: Hi @CBroe ```Unsupported post request```

Comment: Then you probably don't have the correct permissions to perform the action. I would recommend that you figure out the request specifics in Graph API Explorer first, and once you got it properly working in there, you can implement the same in your own code.

Comment: Hi @CBroe That's the problem, in my Javascript project it works perfectly. But in Python, unfortunately not.